# How to set the full file path for a SFTP connector in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-functions

Is this how you would specify the full path when using the External File trigger on an FTP or SFTP connector?

```
{
 "bindings": [ 
   { "type": "apiHubFileTrigger", 
     "name": "inputFile", 
     "direction": "in", 
     "path": "/C:/SFTP_Root/test/Inbound/{name}", 
     "connection": "sftp_SFTP" 
   }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file) to the Microsoft docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that that is the correct way to reference the full file path.
I created a Logic App to the same SFTP server and mapped it to the folder that I needed.

Then I ran some tests to make sure it could see the files in that directory.

I opened the Logic App in the Code View to see how it sored the path.

```
"path": "/C:/SFTP_Root/test/Inbound/{name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the path to something like: "test/Inbound/{name}"

Comment: I need to set the full path because the files are not in the users home directory.

Comment: You can only set the path to where the user has access to. This path is relative to where your sftp_SFTP connection for the user is defined.

Comment: The easier way to test is try to create a Logic App with this sftp connection and make it work there. whatever path works there will also work here.

Comment: The user has access to other areas. Their home directory is their windows directory and the SFTP directory is in another location.